# PHP ldaps unable to connect but ldp connects

Tags: php, linux, ldap

I'm trying to connect to my active directory using SSL as follows:

```
$ldap = ldap_connect('ldaps://server.local/', 636) or die("Couldn't connect to AD!");
```

But it keeps failing to bind. I'm running PHP 7 on Ubuntu Linux 20.10. It seems putting the port number (636) in that syntax makes no difference because regardless of what port number I put. I could put some random high number and as long as I put ldap:// it works, but the minute I put ldaps:// it fails. So it seems like it doesn't know what port ldaps is supposed to be maybe?

Any ideas how I can solve this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [ldap_connect()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-connect.php)

You can do host, port:

> ldap_connect(string $host = null, int $port = 389): resource|false

Or URI:

> ldap_connect(?string $uri = null): resource|false

You're trying to do both at the same time:

```
ldap_connect('ldaps://server.local/', 636)
```

You should use:

```
ldap_connect('ldaps://server.local:636')
```

Comment: I just tried ldap_connect('ldaps://server.local:636') or die("Couldn't connect to AD!"); but it still does not work. Says unable to bind

Comment: What is the full text of the error message?

Comment: ahh i fixed it now i had to put TLS_REQCERT never in the /etc/ldap/ldap.conf file and that solved the problem. Thanks